# Базовая HTTP-аутентификация на django

Tags: python, django

Здравствуйте, необходимо реализовать на django базовую http аутентификацию, это делается  для интеграции с платежной системой.
  Что-то не совсем понимаю как это базовая http аутентификация. Если можно маленький пример  или разъяснить. Заранее спасибо!

Answer (score 1):

Речь идет о HTTP Basic Authentication. Делается ответом 401 на неавторизованные запросы и проеркой заголовка `Authorization` (`request.META["HTTP_AUTHORIZATION"]`) на имя пользователя и пароль.

Суть:

```
# По умолчанию — неавторизован
user = None

# Если есть заголовок `Authorization`, проверяем его.
if "HTTP_AUTHORIZATION" in request.META:
    # В заголовке basic-авторизации две части, разделенных пробелом.
    auth = request.META["HTTP_AUTHORIZATION"].split()
    # Первая — слово "Basic"
    if len(auth) == 2 and auth[0].lower() == "basic":
        # Затем base64-кодированные имя пользователя и пароль,
        # разделенные (после декодирования) двоеточием.
        username, password = base64.b64decode(auth[1]).split(":")
        # Их и используем с django.contrib.auth.authenticate
        user = authenticate(username=username, password=password)

# Если не авторизовали — даем ответ с 401, требуем авторизоваться
if user is None or not user.is_active():
    response = HttpResponse()
    response.status_code = 401
    # realm — любое уникальное (в пределах действия имения пользователя и пароля)
    # имя, например, "API" или "Private area"
    response["WWW-Authenticate"] = 'Basic realm="%s"' % realm
    return response
```

Более полный пример: http://djangosnippets.org/snippets/243/

Comment: может что-то я не догнал вот пример:


    import requests
    url = 'http://test.test/callback/'
    user = 'test'
    passwd = 'test'
    headers = {'User-Agent': 'billing'}
    payload = {'amount': '10'}
    r = requests.post(url, headers=headers, data=payload,  auth=(user, passwd))

делаю:
   def pay(request):
    f = open("/tmp/request","w")
    f.write("%s" %request)
    return render(request, 'test.html')

 в мета нет HTTP_AUTHORIZATION

Comment: Так, уточню. Вам надо принять запрос или отправить его?

Если отправить — Ваш код с `requests.post` полностью то, что надо. Если принять — см. мой ответ, если нет `HTTP_AUTHORIZATION` то отвечайте 401. Не пойму почему в запросе Authorization нет, должен быть.

Comment: Уведомления отправляются по протоколу HTTPS в одном из форматов по выбору:
•
XML (Content-Type: text/xml);
•
HTML (Content-Type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded).
Запрос отправляется методом POST на URL, указанный в свойстве сайта «URL для доставки 
уведомлений».
На сайте партнера на указанном URL должна быть настроена базовая HTTP-аутентификация с 
реквизитами доступа, соответствующими тем, что указаны в свойствах сайта. Если 
аутентификация не настроена, уведомление не доставляется.

Comment: Вот тут я и тупонул, если можно еще раз на путь истинный направь)

Comment: В первом комментарии, `http://test.test/callback/` это та самая вьюшка `pay`?

Если там нет request.META["HTTP_AUTHORIZATION"] то ее кто-то сожрал. Я сейчас проверил, requests сразу же отправляет авторизацию:

    print requests.get('http://httpbin.org/headers', headers={'User-Agent': 'test'}, auth=('username', 'password')).text
    {
      "headers": {
        ...
        "User-Agent": "test", 
        ...
        "Authorization": "Basic dXNlcm5hbWU6cGFzc3dvcmQ="
      }
    }

Честно говоря, не знаю в чем дело. Может быть, веб-сервер сжирает заголовок?

Comment: В общем, по идее, должно приходить в `pay` запрос с заголовком `Authorization` и его разбирать подобно тому, как в моем ответе написано, и все должно работать. Почему его нет — странно. Мои предположения, что то-ли какая-то middleware его съела, то-ли веб-сервер.